# Google Map marker not staying constant when setting marker lattitude and longitude via variables

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polymer-1.0

In my map im trying to set the marker via {{lattitude}} and {{longitude}} variables

However I see that when I set the data via this variable the marker always stays at the middle of the screen. As in while zooming or dragging the map the position of the marker changes and doesnot show the right address.

When I hardcode the values of lattitude and longitude it shows just fine.

Below is my code

```
<google-map latitude="{{lattitude}}" longitude="{{longtitude}}" min-zoom="9" max-zoom="11" language="en">
    <google-map-marker latitude="{{lattitude}}" longitude="{{longtitude}}" title="Go Giants!" draggable="false" drag-events> </google-map-marker>
</google-map>
<script>
</script>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "map-locations",
        properties: {
            lattitude: String,
            longtitude: String,
            title: String
        }
    });
</script>
```

Can some one please help me out with this

Comment: what if you set `draggable: true` on the marker?

Comment: done that @duncan no use :(

Answer (score 0):

Here are examples that I have done some time ago.

[Save the marker position as the user moves it on draggable map.](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qn4gAcEpzyc1zAZMpsFB?p=preview)

[Save the marker position as the user moves it on non-draggable map.](http://plnkr.co/edit/oQv2sPHBirN8FGlcrXTP?p=preview)

```
draggable_map: function() {

           //How to make google-map to fitToMarkers and AGAIN to be draggable?
           //fitToMarkers is conditional attribute, so just disable it after the resize().
           this.fitToMarkers_init = false;
},
```

Can't remember the exact play with the attributes that will solve your problem, but hope this will help.

Comment: I fixed this issue by changing the data type. What was happening that the parent data type from where the lattitude and longitude variables were getting set were set as String. The maps work fine once i changed them to  Number :(